# Failed to process GhostScript command

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, pdf, ghostscript

```
public void ConvertPdfPageToImage(string outputFileName, int pageNumber)
    {
      if (pageNumber < 1 || pageNumber > this.PageCount)
        throw new ArgumentException("Page number is out of bounds", "pageNumber");

      using (GhostScriptAPI api = new GhostScriptAPI())
        api.Execute(this.GetConversionArguments(this._pdfFileName, outputFileName, pageNumber, this.PdfPassword, this.Settings));
    }
```

I'm using the above Method to convert each page of the pdf to image in asp.net. It is working fine with some pdfs. But while using some other pdfs, it is converting only some pages and displaying "Failed to process GhostScript command. Error Code:-100" error message. 
**Note:**Memory size of the pdf is not the issue here.

Comment: Use iTextSharp instead of GhostScript. its easy and better support is available on internet

Comment: if you want to fetch images from pdf then yes it can be used. But if you want convert pdf pages to image then m not sure

Comment: There's really not much to go on here. You haven't supplied an example file to look at, you haven't given the Ghostscript command line you are using, nor have you supplied any of the error messages which Ghostscript might be displaying. You also haven't told us the version of Ghostscript you are using, and you haven't indicated whether the problem is determinisitc (ie if you send the same file twice do you get the same error in the same place). Without that the best I can say is 'something is wrong' which you clearly already know.... *If* that's a Ghostscript error then its 'Fatal error'

Comment: I mean that error code -100 means 'Fatal Error' the actual problem report would have been sent to stdout.

Comment: @Patel full source code samples (good patterns) using iTextSharp for minimize learning curve?

Comment: Hit same issue :( , Using Cyotek.GhostScript.GhostScriptAPI.